# markdown [ creates underline in vim

Tags: vim, markdown

I am writing notes with markdown in Vim.

[image]

When I use `[` as you can see in the following image, it adds unnecessary underlines.

I am wondering if there is any way to avoid this problem.

Thank in advance.

[image]

=========
UPDATE: There seems to be a problem with an `<` in markdown. As you can see in the following image.

Only way I can avoid this is adding `:syntax off`.

[image]

Comment: all I can say is that it's thinking that you wrote a url like that `[label](url)`

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: Most likely, but that shouldn't apply between backticks. Could there be a mismatched backtick earlier in the file?

Comment: I think it's a problem in the syntax file. I've had that for a while but never really cared to fix it.

Comment: @shin did you install any markdown-related plugins? did you wrote your own customized syntax file? It could also happen if you have "special" settings in your colorscheme or your vimrc. without knowing these information, we cannot give suggestions.

Comment: It looks as though some syntax file is going haywire, styling too much as a link.  You can use `:scriptnames` to see what files (plugin, syntax, and other) have been `source`d.  It might be easier to use the example under `:help synID()` to figure out what syntax group is active in the underlined region:  `echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")`.  If it turns out to be markdownFoo, then you can use `:verbose syn list markdownFoo` to find out where the syntax group was defined.

Comment: I started getting this error and turns out if was being caused by setting the link's label to an url. For example: `[https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/)`. It works fine with `[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)`. I also have a related issue in Sublime Text / MarkdownExtended: trying to open in a browser `[https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/)` using the **Open in Browser** action will try to open the url `https://stackoverflow.com/%5D(https://stackoverflow.com/`. I guess it's a markdown thing.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see this problem and just tried your example but was not able to reproduce the underline.  If you are not using it, you might want to setup Tim Pope's [markdown](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown) or [this](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) one by plasticboy.  I have used both and never seen this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used to be frustrated like you, none of the existing plugins for markdown seems to be complete enough, out of my frustration I wrote my plugin https://github.com/gabrielelana/vim-markdown try it, you wont be disappointed ;-)